# Markup language for humans

Tags: markup

I am looking for a markup language for human, to describe a group of physical objects and their characteristics (size, position, type…). I know about [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) but I would like to know if anything else exists. It must be simple, readable and editable for non skilled users.

XML-like markup language are too complicated: users must be able to edit directly a description of physical objects such as:

```
Objects
    object1
        x position: 5cm
        y position: 10cm
        height: 20cm
        width: 30cm
        height: 20cm
        …
```

I am not even sure if that kind of user will know what an indent is. Of course I can tell them how to edit in a documentation file but I must be as close to human writing as possible.

Comment: Was YAML really the only thing that came up in your research?

Comment: This is a very open ended question, but many other markups exist and how readable they are tends to be how well they are written, for example

XML is a good choice here if your schema designed well they can be easily human readable, I take it you have rejected xml, or it somehow doesn't suit your needs Personally i started using YAML last year for things that humans needed to read easily and so far I have no complaints from anyone

Comment: @Marcin For my purpose yes, do you have anything else in mind?

Comment: rooofl No, not least because I have no idea what your purpose is. This sounds like an application where XML could be perfect, but as @krystanhonour does, I assume you have already rejected that for some reason which you have chosen not to reveal.

Comment: @Marcin you are right, I edited my request trying to be more precise.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason the users need to edit the markup directly could you not write a simple application that they enter data into a form or via a number of checkboxes etc and alter it yourself programatically not entirely sure why non skilled user would be editing a file of this nature surely a user of this nature would prefer a nice application

Comment: It is part of an art project where raw documentation is fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that xml is too complicated. It is excellent for key-value representations where you know the keys ahead of time:

```
<object name="Object1"
        x-position="5cm" />
```

You will probably have to mess around with DTDs to get your xml processor to treat the tag as self-closing.